# Pseudocode about GTIN codes

Tags: python, pseudocode

I have to write a piece of software on python that allows the user to enter either a 7 digit GTIN code, for the software to then calculate the check digit, or for the user to enter an 8 digit GTIN code which will then have the last digit - other wise known as the check digit - validated. I have attempted to do this but am not sure if I have done so correctly.

Here is my pseudocode so far:

Input gtin code

If gtin code == 7 then

Function check digit()

Elseif:

Function validate()

If gtin code ==7 then

Output(your completed gtin code is “,gtin code,check digit)

Endif

Def validate()

Run check digit()

If check digit == value 8 then

Output(Your gtin 8 code is correct)

Elseif:

Output(Your gtin 8 code is incorrect, it should be “, check digit)

Comment: "I have attempted to do this but am not sure if I have done so correctly. " So you expect us to test your software?

Comment: No I was simply requestion confirmation if this appears to look in the format of pseudo code. Sorry for any confusion.